# Arabic character base64 encoding issue

Tags: iphone, encoding, base64

I am encoding a string to base64 encoded data.

*Edit: removed irrelevant base64 conversion code*

Is there would be any problem when I trying to encode a mixed english and arabic data, because we are here using

```
    base64Data = [string dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
```

I heard that NSASCIIStringEncoding should not be used with Unicode encoded string.

Answer (score 1):

[Base64](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64) encodes data (raw bytes) and produces ASCII encoded strings. So your problem is in converting your string into an encoded byte array.

You could use any encoding that contains arabic and english characters. But you have to make sure the recipient of the base 64 encoded message would understand and know the encoding.

UTF-8 is a good point to start.